# Compass protocol error with import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

Use rails 4 + compass-rails 2.0.alpha.0 on vagrant ubuntu guest box with windows 8 host.

after making @import 'ico/*.png'; have an error:

```
Protocol error - /vagrant/tmp/cache/assets/development/sass/33b03b948d3279e6e66ff345db8da54afe7f01c3/*.pngc
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue and have tried a few different fixes, currently there's an open issue on the Compass Github for it. https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/98

Answer (score 0):

This is a compatibility issue between VirtualBox and Sass.

1) Setup a directory outside of the shared folder, for example (if your user is `railsuser`)

```
mkdir /mnt/tmp
chown railsuser:railsuser /mnt/tmp
```

2) On `application.rb`

```
# tmp dir for cache must be setup outside virtualbox shared folder for sass cached sprites to work
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore.new('/mnt/tmp')
end
```

For details see the [issue discussion on Github](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/98#issuecomment-71337637).